# Responsive, jQuery and .resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, reload

I want different functionality depending on size, and this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth();
    location.reload();
});
```

doesn't seem to be working.

```
var windowsize = $(window).width();
// resize browser
function checkWidth() {

    if (windowsize > 700) {
        $('#list').show();
        $('#nav_bu').hide();
        showcased();
        $('.project a').attr('href', '#top_shade');
    }
    else {
        accordion();
        $('.showcase').hide();
        $('#nav_bu').show();
    }
}
// on load
checkWidth();
```

Please check out http://kirkradish.com/2013/kirk3.html

Comment: Welcome to SO, please describe "doesn't seem to be working"? You may also want to use http://jsfiddle.net/ to mock up and exmaple.

Comment: hey check my link, both function run when both sizes are met. how can i stop on after it starts, or refresh to only have one running at a time?

Answer (score 3):

You set `windowsize` once, but this is classically the one variable that is bound to change when resized.
Just put this line:

```
var windowsize = $(window).width();
```

into your function:

```
function checkWidth() {
    //here we go:
    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    if (windowsize > 700) {
        $('#list').show();
        $('#nav_bu').hide();
        showcased();
        $('.project a').attr('href', '#top_shade');
    }
    else {
        accordion();
        $('.showcase').hide();
        $('#nav_bu').show();
    }
}
```

And stuff like this:

```
  $('#list').show();
  $('#nav_bu').hide();
```

is classically stuff that you would do with media queries as another user posted.

Comment: I put it back inside, but still wont reload. I had it inside earlier, i only put it outside to see if it would change. If a reload happens on resize, I think that would fix it.

Comment: I would take that `location.reload();` out. No reason for it. `$(window).resize(checkWidth);`

Comment: Your link is broken, don't think we can help you without

Comment: Could you edit out the location part and put the windowsize var back into your function? It should work then.

Comment: after resizing to both widths, not both functions are running, how do I stop one function if both are running?

Comment: I'd recommend you overthink your approach to intensively use `.show()` and `.hide()`. Best would be to write a css class that controls `display: none`. Then you add and remove classes.
For your problem: You could unbind the click events on resize. But I heavily recommend you refactor your code or look around how other websites handle resize (or look at fluid webdesign tutorials).

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that. This is my first responsive site.

Answer (score 2):

Try using media queries.

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { ... }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @KirkRadish why wouldn't you move the show/hide business into CSS in that case?

Comment: +1. This is by far a much cleaner approach for responsive design. The javascript based approach using .resize() should be used only when there is no other way and for dynamically rendered content that you have no control over because certain UI widgets tend to re-render themselves every time it is resized. For this reason, the javascript based approach causes a noticable stutter when the window is being resized if there are a lot of widgets.

Comment: the show/hide bit is more of an accordion function. does css3 handle accordion?

Comment: @KirkRadish see CSS transitions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions